# Copy Columns to new Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I'm trying to code in VBA a system that basically copies columns and paste in another workbook, but I got some particularities.

I will try to explain the logical about how the system must work:

```
Select A2 Cell

Select Column A to Cell An #<*different*># from An+1
-example      A
        A1   hey
        A2   hey
        A3   hey
        A4   hey
        A5   ho
            So it would select till line 4.

Select all info from Column "D" from Cell "D2" to "Dn"

Copy

Open a new workbook

Paste into cell "A2" (New Workbook)

Select all info from Column "E" from Cell "E2" to "En" (First Workbook)

Copy

Paste into cell "B2" (New Workbook)

Select all info from Column "F" from Cell "F2" to "Fn" (First Workbook)

Copy

Paste into cell "C2" (New Workbook)

Select all info from Column "G" from Cell "G2" to "Gn" (First Workbook)

Copy

Paste into cell "D2" (New Workbook)

Select all info from Column "H" from Cell "H2" to "Hn" (First Workbook)

Copy

Paste into cell "F2" (New Workbook)

Select all info from Column "I" from Cell "I2" to "In" (First Workbook)

Copy

Paste into cell "G2" (New Workbook)

Save and close the "New Workbook"

Repeat the process analyzing from An+1 to the next different Cell.
```

The `copy` columns will not start in `Cell2`, it will start in `Celln+1` instead and so on...

Comment: Try recording a Macro and edit the resulting code.

Comment: Ive tryed recording it, but i got problems to detect different cells as Ive mentined (An <>An + 1 ) =/

Answer (score 0):

This code should get you in the right direction. Comments are added to the code.

```
Sub CpyColstoNewWB()
Dim x As Long, i As Long
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Add 'Create new workbook

ThisWorkbook.Activate 'Reset the focus

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
    c = 1 'set the col # in the new workbook sheet1
        For x = 4 To 6 'used to loop through col #s
            i = 1 'sets the initial row to start from
                Do Until Cells(i, x) <> .Cells(i + 1, x) 'test the current cell to the cell below it
                        i = i + 1 'if the condition is not met, will loop to the next row
                Loop

            'If the condition is met, will accomplish the below line of code and then start on the next col
            .Range(.Cells(1, x), .Cells(i, x)).Copy wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, c)

            c = c + 1 'adds 1 to the col # to move to the next col
        Next x 'go to the next col
    End With
End Sub
```